# A request's round trip time monitoring at microservice production best tools and practices?

Tags: microservices, latency, monitoring, end-to-end, tracing

I've a microservice's system at production which provide an API to the outer world. Along with each service monitoring via monitoring tool ( Prometheus, zabbix, etc.) of course it's highly desirable to monitor every single request's round trip time. The requests could have different nature: synchronous or asynchronous:

1. a request came to API gateway, goes to MS1, MS2, response to client
2. a request came to API gateway, goes to MS1 -> MessageBroker ...[stay here, client received 201 ] ... -> consumed, handled, pushed to client
   Need to measure these 2 cases.

What are the best tools and practices?

Comment: Hi cpu, welcome to softwareengineering.stackexchange.com. Your question appears to be off-topic per our community guidelines. See: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and  https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess a request tracing can help ( zipkin, sleuth, jager)
presents execution requests as traces. A trace shows the data/execution path through a system